# OpenCV - Getting a percentage confidence for SVM(Support Vector Machines) using Python

Tags: python, opencv, svm

```
opencv_svm.train(imgfeatures, cv2.ml.ROW_SAMPLE, classes)

response = opencv_svm.predict_all(imgfeatures, flags=cv2.ml.STAT_MODEL_RAW_OUTPUT)

print response[1]
```

Currently the OpenCV 3.2.0 SVM examples only show one how to extract predicted labels. How does one extract the confidence value (between 1 and 0) as well? This has to be in python

Comment: you can interpret the distance from the margin, the bigger the (absolute) distance the higher might the confidence: http://answers.opencv.org/question/43239/how-to-get-a-probability-for-a-svm-prediction/ to get a range from 0 to 1 you'd choose some max dist and normalize linear or quadratic or sth.

Comment: I do not get this valye for more than 2 classes